# AC clutch engages no cold air, equal pressure across lines

Tags: honda, ac, accord, compressor

I recently took my Honda Accord to the mechanic and it was found that there was equal pressure on the high and low side AC lines (around 90 psi on an 80°F day). However the clutch was still engaging on the compressor. Is this signs of an internal compressor failure?

And if so, do other components of the AC system need to be replaced in case debris has been spread throughout the system? I ask because this was initially diagnosed as a leak and I have already gotten the condenser and dryer replaced, and I'd rather not do that again.

Lastly, do you recommend replacing the expansion valve along with replacing the compressor? In my research I've seen recommendations to do it and others saying it is unnecessary.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If the expansion valve were acting up you would be seeing greatly inequal pressures, not equal ones. Is it a variable displacement compressor? If so, the displacement control valve might be faulty and the compressor's swash plate might be basically rotating but not pumping at all (even if healthy). But variable pistons are rare on Japanese cars.

Comment: Year of Honda? Engine?

Comment: Check for the AC relay, and 20 amp condenser fan fuse.

Comment: @NumairAidroos The AC relay can't be at fault since the clutch is engaging. An inoperative condenser fan would make the HP line pressure spike up and he's saying that the pressures are equal...

Comment: Sorry about leaving that info out: it's a 2005 Accord, 2.4L 4 cylinder. also @NumairAidroos, yes I do not believe it's the relays or fuse because the clutch is engaging and the condenser fan is indeed operating.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's a fixed displacement compressor (of the Denso 10S type), and if the clutch hub is rotating when you turn AC on but the pressures don't budge, the compressor might have failed indeed, yet the usual failure is straight seizing up.

Comment: Okay that's what I feared. And I thought it was interesting because on a different car (2000 Honda Civic) the compressor failed a few years back, but it failed by completely seizing up like you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, have you tried rotating the clutch hub (engine off and keys in your pocket, suffice to say) with your hands? What do you feel?

Comment: @Al_ I just went and felt around and yes the clutch rotates fine by hand with the engine off. Doesn't seem like there's any resistance.

Comment: You have to feel a smooth resistance across one whole turn (remember that you're rotating an inclined swash plate equipped with 5 double sided pistons). If you feel any rough spots, bad. If you feel no resistance at all, equally bad.